# How do I get all of the messages on my girlfriend's iPhone to come on my phone?

Tags: ios-appstore, messages, iphone

I suspect my girlfriend is cheating. How can I catch my girlfriend and get all of my girlfriend's messages to come on my phone, without having to use her phone? I have looked up different applications on *App Store*, but nothing really works.

Comment: Get a lawyer before you break any laws. Also - when you're looking for software recommendations, we have quality standards so check on [meta] and show your research.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have her stuff, then you can access her messages no easier than you can access any other person's messages. Which, basically, is not easy.

If you have access to her computer, or another device where she has signed in with the Apple ID she uses with her phone, her phone messages may be visible in the Messages app there. The the "SMS" section [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) for more details.

---

This is just to answer your question, but I don't necessarily endorse the cause. Have you tried talking to her about it or breaking up?